# Conversion required from general in to text format in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to convert the value of my variable valueTofind from the general into text format but below the line of code gives me an error, Kindly help me with the updated version of the code.

```
 valuetoFind=rngfound
    valuetoFind.numberformat="@"
```

This variable value changes everytime with the new set of data.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Needs more code.  You may be missing a `Set` but it's difficult to say for sure.

Comment: By the sound of your variable name, if you used `.Find(...)` for rngfound, only proceed `If Not rngfound Is Nothing Then`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments above say, hard to know without seeing your declarations.

But the correct syntax would be:

Set rngFound = Range(x:y)

rngFound.Numberformat = "@"